# How to set only selected properties using .NET DbPropertyValues.SetValues?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to write some code that allows me to update a detached entity using the Entity Framework.
So far, the code looks like this:

```
    public virtual void UpdateUnattached(T entity, string lookupPropertyName, string primaryKeyPropertyName)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot update a null entity.");
        }

        // Get the data entry associated with the unattached entity from the context.
        var entry = DataContext.Entry<T>(entity);

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            // Get the already attached entity by the lookup property (which can be different from the primary key).
            var attachedEntity = this.dbSet.Local.SingleOrDefault(
                e => (int)ObjectUtil.GetPropertyValue(e, lookupPropertyName) == (int)ObjectUtil.GetPropertyValue(entity, lookupPropertyName)
            );

            // Get the value of the primary key for the attached entity.
            var primaryKeyValue = ObjectUtil.GetPropertyValue(attachedEntity, primaryKeyPropertyName);

            // Set the primary key of the unattached entity.
            ObjectUtil.SetPropertyValue(entity, primaryKeyPropertyName, primaryKeyValue);

            if (attachedEntity != null)
            {
                // Get the entry associated with the attached entity from the context and set the values of the unattached entity to be updated.
                var attachedEntry = DataContext.Entry(attachedEntity);
                attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
    }
```

On the `attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);` line I would like to set the values for some properties and skip others. This would allow me to make this method more generic by passing the names of the properties I don't want to be updated.
Does anyone know if this is possible? The `SetValues` method has one other overload that accepts a `DbPropertyValues` object but I can't find a way to build this object without the properties I don't want to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks.
I was already on the way to try and use reflection... I ended up replacing the `attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);` call with `SetAttachedEntityValues(attachedEntity, entity, new string[] { "Payout", "Client", "Country" });` which calls a method that copies all properties except the ones specified on the array:

```
    private void SetAttachedEntityValues(T attachedEntity, T entity, string[] excludePropertyNames)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => !excludePropertyNames.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();

        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            var propertyValue = ObjectUtil.GetPropertyValue(entity, property.Name);
            ObjectUtil.SetPropertyValue(attachedEntity, property.Name, propertyValue);
        }
    }
```

`ObjectUtil` is a class that has methods that do pretty much what Yuliam Chandra suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Current values will set all scalar properties.

If you want to have custom mapping, you can use reflection.

```
foreach (var name in propertyNames)
{
    var value = entity.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(entity, null);
    attachedEntity.GetType().GetProperty(name).SetValue(attachedEntity, value);
}
```